# JavaScript Function eval() throwing an out-of-stack quota exception

Tags: javascript, json

Recently I ran into a problem: Valid JSON when passed to the `eval()` function causes it to throw the error -- "script stack space quota is exhausted".

It is consistently reproducible, and through initial examination, it seems that this is a limitation on the number of object attributes/properties that can be defined (and not the size of the content).

Here's the sample code:

```
function starttest()
{      
       var d = new Array(50000);
       var i = 0;

       for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
            d[i] = new Object();
            d[i].a1 = 1;
            d[i].a2 = 2;
            d[i].a3 = i;
            d[i].a4 = i;
            d[i].a5 = i;
            d[i].a6 = i;
            d[i].a7 = i;
            d[i].a8 = i;
            d[i].a9 = i;
            d[i].a10 = i;
            d[i].a11 = i;
            d[i].a12 = i;
            d[i].a13 = i;
            d[i].a14 = i;
            d[i].a15 = i;
       }       



    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(d);  
    alert(jsonString.length);

    var obj = eval(jsonString);
    var count = 0;
    for( var i = 0; i< obj.length; i++) {

        for (var k in obj[i]) {
            if (obj[i].hasOwnProperty(k)) {
               ++count;
            }
        }
    }

    alert("Done! || Len: " + obj.length + " || " + "Attrib Count: " + count + " || " + typeof obj)
}
```

The funny thing is I can define many more objects than seen in the code snippet; the problem arises only when using the `eval()` function.

Any new insights into this would be greatly helpful. I know using `eval()` is not safe, and all... and I'm open to suggestions!

Comment: FWIW, I tested your code in Chrome and IE 9 (beta) and it worked fine.  Ran out of stack space in Firefox 3.6.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this is a problem with Firefox's JavaScript interpreter in general. It's not just `eval`: if you put fifty thousand lines of:

```
{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4,e:5,f:6,g:7,h:8,i:9,j:10,a2:1,b2:2,c2:3,d2:4,e2:5,f2:6,g2:7,h2:8,i2:9,j2:10},
```

in an array literal in a plain script file or `<script>` element, you get exactly the same error.

It seems the complexity of a script block is limited by the compile-time `JS_DEFAULT_SCRIPT_STACK_QUOTA`. See [420869](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=420869) and the related linked bugs.

It's relatively unlikely you should meet this in normal circumstances. Of course for the case of JSON you can use `JSON.parse` which, not being a full JavaScript interpreter, is not affected by this limitation. If you needed a non-valid-JSON JS literal parser that's not affected, I guess you'd have to write it yourself... though it'd probably be annoyingly slow when you get to input this long.

Answer (score 3):

It means what it says. `eval` is obviously using recursion, and you're exceeding your limit when evaluating a long and complex JSON literal.  It works fine with `JSON.parse` (at least in Firefox 3.6.11pre), which is the right tool for the job, and [often faster](http://www.vinylfox.com/json-decoding-speed-comparison/).

Comment: Note, however, that if your browser doesn't have native `JSON.parse`, the implementation defined in http://www.json.org/json2.js uses `eval` internally, so it would have the same issue. `json_parse` (as mentioned in Alex's answer) doesn't. So I'd use native JSON parsing if available, and `json_parse` as a fallback.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the JSON class to create a JSON string. Why don't you just use the opposite function to stringify to get the JSON back into an object syntax?

http://www.json.org/json_parse.js - is the javsacript JSON class. Just call json_parse(str); and you'll get a nice object back.

As you said yourself, eval() is not safe. It's damn-right evil!